# OpenCV Stereo Matching

Tags: opencv, match, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm a newbie to OpenCV. I'm working on a stereo project using 2 webcams. I can display the webcam captures into left and right videos. I want to do the following: When I click on any point on the left frame, I want to find the matching point on the right image (Kinda project the point on the second view using Block Matching or any other algorithm). So I can calculate the disparity. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV's [`StereoVar`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/stereo.html#StereoVar) object would probably be a good starting point.

You can create a `StereoVar` object like this:

```
StereoVar myStereoVar(int levels, double pyrScale,
                                int nIt, int minDisp, int maxDisp,
                                int poly_n, double poly_sigma, float fi,
                                float lambda, int penalization, int cycle,
                                int flags);
```

then match pairs of images like this:

```
// disp will hold correspondences for each pixel in your pair of images.
myStereoVar(InputArray left, InputArray right, OutputArray disp);
```

You might have to transform your `cv::Mat` into an `InputArray`, but this should be pretty simple.

As for clicking on the pixels to see the correspondence, I bet it's possible, but let's worry about this after getting correspondence computation up and running.